# What's the difference between Run and EMULATE in Cordova CLI?

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, genymotion

What's the difference between RUN and EMULATE in Cordova CLI?
I am using Genymotion, and EMULATE doesn't work and gives me error, maybe something isn't set but RUN works and installs my web-app in the emulator, the lines I use are:
cordova run android; (works)
cordova emulate android; (doesn't work)

Comment: I use genymotion emulator. I start a virtual device and then I do: cordova run android. It would be good if I can associate my Genymotion virtual device to the emulate android command

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Run and Emulate is the same, opening the simulator

Answer (score 0):

Cordova Emulate launches an emulator, Cordova Run launches and runs the app on your phone and utilizes USB debugging.

If you're using run to emulate I am guessing you have an emulated device set up separately.

What error are you receiving?